# Post Fetching Ignoring Sort_Column?

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I am using the code below subpages for my portfolio. For some reason, it seems to be ignoring the ordering I have set on my pages. Any help?

```
   <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use the `sort_column` parameter, it's not supported by the `WP_Query()` class. According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), the correct way to sort, is to use the `order` and `orderby` parameters.

Please try this:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
        'order'          => 'ASC',        // DESC is the default order
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```